# jdbc realm with glassfish v3: Realm properties and configuration error

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc, glassfish-3, jdbcrealm

**I have the following database schema (MySQL):**

[image]

My login is a form based authentication system, to which i am trying to create a **jdbc realm.**

[image]

My web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>emdJDBCRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/index.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/loginerror.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Login Page</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>adm</role-name>
        <role-name>usr</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>usr</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>adm</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And the mappings in sun-web.xml:

```
<security-role-mapping>
  <role-name>adm</role-name>
  <group-name>adm</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
  <role-name>usr</role-name>
  <group-name>usr</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

I don't know why but it is not working for me , i get the following :

```
    FINE: Cannot load group
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'group_name' in 'field list'
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
            at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:641)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.findGroups(JDBCRealm.java:480)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:312)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule.authenticate(JDBCLoginModule.java:72)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:90)
            at com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:141)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:341)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:199)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:152)
            at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:479)
            at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:418)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:264)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:1015)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:615)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    FINE: JAAS authentication aborted.
    FINEST: doPasswordLogin fails
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:341)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:199)
            at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:152)
            at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:479)
            at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:418)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:264)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:1015)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:615)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:857)
            ... 34 more

    WARNING: Web login failed: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
```

Am i putting the "accurate" properties based on the database schema that i have? i'd appreciate your help because i couldn't understand what i am doing wrong.

### **UPDATE**

This if for anyone who has the same scenario.

Based on @perissf , GlassFish JDBC Realm doesn't support normalized tables. check @perissf's link for a tutorial on how should the schema be.

**However , what i did is:**
I kept the normalized schema and created a MySQL "view" that contains all required columns : ie columns [username, pass, group_name]

**-->And i modified the Jdbc properties as follow:**
[image]

The reason behind using a "view" is that , as @Matt Handy said **"JdbcRealm requires that the User Name Column name needs to be the same in the User table and in the Group Table"**
So this creates duplicate data in my case, thus i used a view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, `GlassFish JDBC Realm` doesn't support normalized tables for users and groups. I guess that your problem is there. Check out this [tutorial](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/jdbc-security-realm-and-form-based.html) and modify your tables accordingly.

Comment: thx, ur absolutely right i tried your tutorial it worked. However check my UPDATE section, i ended up creating a view and using it (so that i don't have to remove normalization). Do you think using a view has an overhead, or is a bad practice in this case?

Comment: On the contrary, I think that using a view is a smart idea, and I am glad to see that it works!

Comment: @shadesco perissf I wish I could up vote you both a million times, I've been wrestling with this garbage for days. Thank you!

Comment: @Preston my pleasure bro, Glad your problem was solved cheers!

Comment: I am having issue with migration from 4.0 to 4.1.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686737/migration-from-glassfish-4-0-to-glassfish-4-1-1-jdbc-realm-issue

Answer (score 1):

In addition to perissf's answer: JdbcRealm requires that the *User Name Column* name needs to be the same in the *User* table and in the *Group Table* (which is the table that assingns users to groups). So your table `user_info` needs a column `userName` instead of `user_id`.

Comment: thank your for your help . Check my UPDATE section, i ended up creating a view and using it (so that i don't have to remove normalization). Do you think using a view has an overhead, or is a bad practice in this case?

Comment: That sounds good. Is it possible for a user to be member of more than one group with your solution?